# Are homebrew evaluation questions OK?

Tags: discussion, questions, homebrew

What's the stance on asking for feedback on house-ruled material? In my particular case, I wrote a couple of generic moves for [Tremulus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tremulus) (they can probably be extended to AW/DW), changing the wealth system, and wanted to ask if the community could spot any potential pitfalls with them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Magician's quote from chat (*emphasis mine*):

> Is anyone here familiar with AW/DW/tremulus? *Wealth didn't make any sense in the latter*, so I wrote up a couple moves to earn and spend it. There's nothing exciting about them, but I'm wondering if there are any potential problems.

I think homebrew evaluation is OK as long as it's part 2 of a multipart question. For example, "Evaluate my homebrew" is not a valid question. But this is (or at least could be, if phrased properly):

1. Wealth doesn't seem to make sense in Tremulus, am I missing something? (*examples/explanation go here*)
2. If wealth really is messed up in Tremulus, would these fixes work OK? (*list homebrew*)

The two parts are closely related enough to justify being in the same question, since any answer would have to go into how wealth does or doesn't work in Tremulus, and part 1 will be useful to a general audience.

Comment: This looks like a good model to me. Failing a question like this, I think chat is as good as it gets.

Answer (score -3):

I think asking for well parameterized homebrew evaluation is fine by itself.  I'd actually prefer that to 'two part' questions because two part answers make voting hard.