# How far do we do peer reviews?

Tags: discussion, policy

And I am not asking about the general "what do you guys think" questions, but since I noticed we have accepted (meaning reopened) questions like [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26558/help-me-evaluate-this-homebrew-pokemaster-class), if only after extensive editing, is it okay to ask about our own designs? Or should that be left to the forums? I always thought the question would be too localised, but after seeing the question above, I began to doubt.

What is the RPG.SE policy on such questions?

Comment: Relevant: [Homebrew evaluation questions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/2912/4398), [How to deal with feedback questions about house-rules?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/942/4398). Given these, it looks like the answer is "Depends on how they're asked." It's also worth noting that some systems almost *require* such questions; for example, non-generic questions about DFRPG spellcasting must necessarily involve table-level creation.

Comment: Thanks, seems sensible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### This is an absolutely necessary part of the site.

Not only is homebrew a common part of the RPG experience, many engines now require it to one degree or another: for example, non-generic questions about [dresden-files](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dresden-files) spellcasting *must* necessarily involve analyzing table-level invention.

### We seem to be fine-tuning our understanding of "too localized."

And it appears to be based on the idea that if the *topic* could be applied widely (like making spells in DFRPG) then it doesn't matter if the *example* is exceptionally narrow. Only when others could not glean more general understanding from the specific solution does "too localized" come into play. This is one of my own questions that might be seen to fall into the "localized but useful" category: [**How can I turn invisible?**](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/21660/4398)

### But they don't get a free pass where other questions wouldn't.

Based on these questions and their answers:

- [**Homebrew evaluation questions**](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2912/4398)
- [**How to deal with feedback questions about house-rules?**](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/942/4398)

it looks like the answer is that such questions are excellent provided they follow the standard site guidelines for asking questions. In particular, ["you" should be sure to avoid cases where...](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

- your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
- there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
- you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”

And remember that experience-based answers will be much better than theory-based answers in this context.

Answer (score 6):

**Acceptable**: "Here is a thing I made, here is its design goal, does this look like it would fulfill the goal or am I missing something important?"

**Not acceptable**: "Here is a thing I made, what do you think?"

Note that the latter will probably be hit with a lot of close votes of the "too broad", "unclear what you're asking", or "mostly opinion based" variety (depending on its exact phrasing). That's a good test of whether the question you're asking is a good fit for the site – if you were a potential answerer reading just the text on the screen, would any of the close reasons seem appropriate?